# Library for scanning barcodes with iPad 2 front camera?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, barcode, barcode-scanner

Which libraries are available for scanning barcodes with the iPad 2 front camera - not the back camera?

The library in the best case features image processing functionality to make up for the missing autofocus.

Related: Which barcode would you suggest for best recognition rate (for an ID with about 8 digits)?

Answer (score 0):

The `objc` directory in [ZXing](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/) has Objective C wrapper classes that interface to the ZXing C++ port and provide for camera selection. There's not much in the way of documentation for the `objc` classes but there is a [sample macruby app](https://github.com/smparkes/zxing.rb) that may work as a guide.

The ZXing C++ port is most reliable on QR codes. There is 1D code support, but it's not heavily used. If you're going to be reading with a fixed-focus camera, QR codes are generally much more reliably read than 1D codes.